# How do I reduce the frequency of electric current for part of a circuit that has variable frequencies?

Tags: audio, frequency, signal-processing

I want to reduce the frequency of electrical current that is operating in the 220 to 240 khz range, to being a maximum of 20khz.  I want it to still be variable though, and the magnitude of variation to be the same (so 240 kHz for the part of circuit operating at high frequency becomes 20 kHz on the low frequency part,  and 220 kHz becomes either 0 kHz (subtracting the frequency to get it below the maximum), or about 18 kHz if we scale it down by 12 (240/12=20, 220/12= appr. 18.33).  Really I just want to know how to isolate a part of a circuit and have it shift the frequency of the electrical current down to a frequency that is compatible with being heard when sent through a speaker.  The magnitude of the reduction for each side doesn't matter, it doesn't even need to be equal, as long as it remains variable but is reduced to a hearable frequency.

Extra Details:  The circuit I have already converts DC current into pulsed current using Schmitt triggers.  This pulse is sent into an induction coil to create a pulsed em field at the same frequency.  If a conductive material or ferrous metal goes within the effective range of the pulsed em field, it induces current in the material and generates its own em field, which affects the pulse going through the induction coil, changing the frequency that the current is at.  I want to be able to detect that change in frequency.  Most methods involve converting it into sound through various means, one being to wrap some wire from the circuit around an AM radio, another being directly connecting it to a speaker of some sort along with an amplifier, but only after converting it to frequency that the speaker will output within the human hearing range.

Comment: So ... something like a Heterodyne-type [Bat Detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat_detector)?

Comment: Perhaps, but for an electric circuit.  The circuit is operating at around 230 kHz with variation, and I want to hear the variation.  I found a way to pipe the signal to a speaker but, the signal is currently to high to be heard, and the speaker may not even be able to emit sound at that frequency.

Comment: Instead of bat sound being converted to human hearable sound, electric current being reduced to a frequency that will allow the signal to be heard when sent through a speaker.

Comment: I'm not proposing you use an actual 'bat detector', just asking if that's the kind of functionality you're looking for (and if so, giving you a hint for the sort of circuit you'll need to research).

Comment: I guess it could work something like that, but considering this is an electrical signal first, I would like to convert the electric signal to a lower frequency and then pipe it to a speaker, than pipe the raw signal to the speaker and then a heterodyne to be piped to another speaker.  Or does the heterodyne system convert bat sound to electric signal and decrease that electric signal to a lower frequency and then pipe that lower frequency current to a speaker?  The article wasn't quite clear on that to be honest.

Comment: The heterodyne circuit is the bit which 'decreases the frequency'. It doesn't care where the signal comes from or goes to.

Comment: Is the "hearing" part essential for your solution or you just want to detect changes in frequency? If the latter, then what's wrong with simple oscilloscope?

Comment: Having read the thing about the heterodyne circuit, that looks exactly like what I need.  Not sure about the values of everything though (capacitors, size of induction coils, etc etc).  This is current running through a breadboard by the way.

Comment: Most oscilloscopes as I understand them are too big.  Could they fit on a small breadboard?  Also the change in frequency may be very small.

Comment: I would buy the heterodyne circuit, but most of the ones I have found so far seem to operate in the Mhz range.

Comment: be aware that a simple heterodyne down-converter has a "flaw"...your 220 kHz local oscillator example down-converter cannot distinguish a 240 kHz bat chirp from a 200 kHz bat chirp - both bat chirps will emerge from the down-converter @ 20 kHz. It *is possible* to build a down-converter without this "flaw" - it is complex.

Answer (score 3):

Having read through all the comments and the question I would consider using a phase locked loop (PLL) circuit that has upper and lower limits of 240 kHz and 220 kHz. The PLL would then produce a DC output voltage that was directly related to the frequency of the signal between these two limits. This technique is called frequency demodulation.

I think the [LM565](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNza7o-OHbAhVBdcAKHX7FD1wQFghRMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.egr.msu.edu%2Feceshop%2FParts_Inventory%2Fdatasheets%2Flm565cn.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3M-4Ds6j8HLd1SD4HPMK2U) would prove quite suitable as a frequency demodulator as it operates up to 300 kHz: -

[image]

If you find it hard getting that chip the [74HC4046 PLL](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdjKmb-uHbAhWOTcAKHQ4rDu0QFghCMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Fcd74hc4046a.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1Al7hmWCH242qF--Xz0qJL) is available.

To turn that DC voltage (the PLL output) to audio requires a simple voltage controlled oscillator circuit such as this: -

[image]

Virtually any op-amp would work in the above circuit

Comment: I like the fact that you had circuit diagrams in your answer.  The solution you provide is both a bit more complex than I would like but also less complex at the same time.  More parts to the circuit than I would hope, but at least the parts used are simple ones (IC, resistors, and capacitors as far as I can tell, and two logic gates I think in the bottom picture).  Just to clarify though, what is R3 in the bottom picture connecting to?  It has an arrow pointing to a line.  And what is the difference between output one and two?

Comment: It’s a JFET. A type of FET.

Comment: Sorry, I am horrible with acronyms.  Not sure what that is.

Comment: It stands for "junction field effect transistor" and it is an N channel type.

Comment: The triangles are some sort of logic gate right?  Not entirely sure what kind though.  Also what is output one and two?

Comment: They are op-amps.

Comment: Ah I see.  Didn't know the symbol for that.  And what are the two outputs?  Are both used?

Comment: Output 1 is a triangular shaped wave and 2 is a square wave.

Answer (score 0):

Division of frequency makes it to hear the shift, while a linear  mixer to filter the difference frequency output with a tuneable 220kHz Local Oscillator (LO) will give the desired result. (aka super 
heterodyne down-shifter)

However if the bat  uses swept continuous or discrete frequencies you get a Doppler shift in phase and frequency of the echos for position and velocity.

Thus a tuneable software defined radio or DSP hardware (DSP-SDR) using acoustic input may be a better solution to compress the frequency shifts might give a more real-time human audible tone.

You can then record it on a laptop with audacity.exe (free ) and provide further superhet processing in frequency domain or view spectrum on a log scale. And measure echo times. (But not in stereo)

I assume you have a microphone capable of detecting this carrier frequency of sound chirps.  (High gain piezo sensor/amp with parabolic dish positioned for high directional gain and filtered 20kHz to 240 kHz

But all depends on the breed of bat and it’s change in tune towards a target.   Slowing down in Audacity is easy . Thus stretching the time x 10 while reducing the frequency and preserving the amplitude . Then the Doppler shift in echos received for each downward sweeping tone gives the distance relative to the velocity between bat and moving or stationary targets.

https://www.wildlife-sound.org/resources/equipment/2-uncategorised/233-recordings-of-ultrasonic-vocalisations-of-bats

Comment: Just to clarify, I am trying to distinguish frequency changes in an electric circuit, possibly through hearing the frequency coming out of a speaker change, but that requires that the electric frequency be converted to a frequency that can be heard when it comes through a speaker.

Comment: Did you hear the audio in the link I posted slowed down /10?  This is the best way to hear the differences. It sounds like bird chirps but if 10x faster , harder to tell the difference.  Thus superthet then stretch in Audacity

Comment: @cluemein  I think your question is wrong. I doubt any bats limited to only the spectrum between 220 to 240 khz range . If I am wrong which bats?

Comment: I'm not looking for bats. Someone else brought up the idea of the bat detector.  I am talking about electricity being sent through a circuit that changes frequency due to the effects of external electromagnetic fields on an induction coil.  The circuit's normal operating frequency is around 230 kHz I think, or something close to that.  This frequency is created by DC power from a battery being converted to pulsed power by a Schmitt trigger.  This pulsed power is then sent through an induction coil, creating a pulsing em field.

Comment: When electrically conductive materials or ferrous materials are exposed to this em field, they produce their own em field that interferes with the original pulse, causing the pulse to change in frequency due to the magnetic field not dissipating at the normal frequency.

Comment: Ah That is clearer and your purpose ought to be in Question.   This mutual coupling effect or change in inductance can easily be measured with a CD4046 PLL with V vs f output. Using a  LPF wide enough to capture initial frequency error quickly and VCO range to be slightly more than you need to get 2.5~4.5V range on VCO approx (from memory 30Yrs ago). This is why it is better for WPT to track resonance or be self resonant

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good with acronyms.  What is LPF and WPT?

Comment: Low pass filter and wireless (inductive) power transfer technology are very common terms in that industry